# How to edit the css style of validation ng-class error

Tags: css, angularjs

My question is very simple:
How can I edit the css style of the `ng-class` validation error 'error' of bootstrap v3?

Here is my code:

```
ng-class="(form.datos.$invalid) && ( form.datos.$touched || submitted) ? 'error': '' "
```

The error style here is a background red which I didn't like I want to change it to another color.

Comment: http://formvalidation.io/examples/changing-success-error-colors/ check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should overrite the css but if you want to do it with angular you could use `ng-style` directive, and it would look like

```
ng-style="(form.datos.$invalid) && ( form.datos.$touched || submitted) && {'background-color':'#00F'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really Angular related but anyway.

Put your file import after bootstrap's one in your HTML, and simply do

```
.error {
    background-color: transparent; /* or whatever */ 
}
```

You might use

```
.error {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

But it's not recommended.

Comment: where to put it exactly? i tried a lot of thing which didn't work here is my whol input feild : 'code'<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-class="(form.datos.$invalid) && ( form.datos.$touched || submitted) ? 'error': '' "
      name="datos" placeholder="Escribir ..." id="datos"
      ng-model="vm.peticion.contacto.solicitante" ng-maxlength="50" required/>

Comment: This is a CSS file, so put it in your css file and import your css file in your header. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: yeah i did it and it doesn't work anyway i used the code above of taguenizy and it works fine :) thank you so much